# After update ember-cli 2.11.0 version how to npm instead of bower?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

When I updated `ember-cli` to `2.11.0` and I found `EMBER NO LONGER SUPPLIED VIA bower`. So I check npm instead of bower, but I don't know what to do.

Such as `moment.js` use bower look like:

bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "moment": "2.14.1"
}
```

ember-cli-build.js

```
...
app.import('bower_components/moment/moment.js');
...
```

.jshintrc

```
...
"moment": true,
...
```

This way can run in `help` and `controller`.

But I use `npm` and set `ember-cli-build.js` code `app.import('node_modules/moment/moment.js');` had errors.

And `css`aslo have this problem.

What is best way to npm instead of bower in ember-cli? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Through [ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify)

   `npm install ember-browserify --save-dev`
   `npm install moment --save-dev`

you can import it by `import moment from 'npm:moment'`

2. Try [ember-cli-moment-shim](https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-cli-moment-shim)
3. ember packages are not served through `bower`. It does not mean you can't use bower at all. You can still use `bower.json` and include it like you did.
4. You can have it in `vendor` folder and include it `ember-cli-build.js` file . but for moment.js inclusion. this is not the right way.

I prefer 1 or 2 options. and 3 and 4 is not applicable in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I know can use `bower` I just try all use npm. I check `ember-browserify` document, it can not show how to use for css file.

Comment: which package you want to include ?

Comment: bootstrap and `pace.js` css file.

Comment: For example, I know `ember-font-awesome` this package, but I did not use because I try to not use `bower` and use `font-awesome` npm.

Comment: I choose `bower`. if I don't want `bower ` then i will choose 4th option `vendor`. I am not sure about the best options and other posssible options too. For bootstrap you might [ember-bootstrap addon](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap)

Comment: After your answer, I think is not time to use npm instead of bower in ember cli.