# Is it right to try moving my front end packages from bower to npm?

Tags: ember.js, npm, bower, npm-install, bower-install

I am quite new to ember and was trying to build a small to-do list app when I started facing a problem wherein I tried installing *moment* package through `bower install moment` but somehow importing the package into *ember-cli-build.js* didn't work out. I came across a solution that said I should run`npm install moment` over it and that worked for me. 
Following above events I tried removing the moment package from bower_components and changing the path to node_modules. This didn't work out though and broke my app instead. I was getting the following error:

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [SourceMapConcat: Concat: Vendor /assets/vendor.js] failed with: 

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kshitij/scratch/ember-projects/em-app/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-UJQvdiAo.tmp/node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js
```

**My question**: Is trying moving bower packages to npm correct? If yes, then why it doesn't work out in this case?

**Note:** I could also have solved the problem by adding "moment" to "predef" block of *.jshint.rc* file in the application directory but I want to know why the npm method worked out and why porting the *moment* package entirely from bower to npm doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In `ember-cli-build.js`, you can only mention `vendor` folder or `bower_components` folder, you can not mention `node_modules` folder.

You don't need to do `npm install moment` or `bower install moment` for installing moment packages to ember, you can just do `ember install ember-moment` that is equivalent to `npm install ember-moment --save-dev` and `ember g moment`

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42083763/5771666) for possible way including moment packages.

Comment: Thanks, will try importing the package as mentioned in the linked answer.